# Python Multiple IFs and then 1 ELSE

Tags: python, if-statement

A python newbie here. I just have a question about my code:

```
name=input('What is the name?')
if name=='Spathiphyllum':
    print ('Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!')
if name=='spathiphyllum':
    print ('No, I want a big Spathiphyllum!')
else:
    print('Spathiphyllum! Not', name,'!')
```

When I execute this with Spathiphyllum as input, it also prints out the else output. How do I correct this? Thank you[image]

Comment: Replace the middle if with `elif`  (else if).

Answer (score 1):

The `else` only refers to the last `if` part. And since the second `if` does not execute, you end up in the `else`. If you want more than 2 conditional branches, you use any number of `elif` inbetween the if-else:

```
if name == 'Spathiphyllum':
    print('Spathiphyllum is the best plant ever!')
elif name == 'spathiphyllum':
    print('No, I want a big Spathiphyllum!')
else:
    print('Spathiphyllum! Not', name,'!')
```